# short time energy matlab code for audio feature extraction

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-analysis

Is there code in matlab for short time energy feature extraction in matlab??

I want to extract audio feature (Short time energy) using matlab code

Comment: There is no function like that in MATLAB. In fact this not a solved problem i.e. not known clearly.

Answer (score 4):

Short time energy (STE) is simple feature and so is the code to compute it.

```
ste = sum(buffer(signal.^2, winLen));
```

where  and winLen is duration of rectangular time window (in samples).

If you want to use diffrent shape of window, then you have to multiply each column returned by buffer by this window, before you sum the columns.

Comment: Note that there are different definitions of short term energy. The definition used in this answer by @skywalker is also used by Rabiner and Schafer in the book Digital Speech Processing. This equation appears on page 249 (noting that rectangular window used as above):

$$
E(\hat{n}) = \sum\limits_{m = -\infty}^\infty (x[m]w[\hat{n}-m])^2 = \sum\limits_{m = -\infty}^\infty (x[m])^2 \tilde{w} [\hat{n}-m]
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is code on the matlab file exchange which can do exactly what you are asking for.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23571-short-time-energy-and-zero-crossing-rate